# $k$ is algebraically closed $\Leftrightarrow$ $\forall f \in k[X,Y], V(f)\neq\{(0,0)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. I want to show that
$k$ is algebraically closed if and only if for all $f\in k[X,Y],V(f)=\{(a,b)\in k^2|f(a,b)=0\}\neq\{(0,0)\}$.

I proved that for all $f\in k[X,Y],V(f)=\{(a,b)\in k^2|f(a,b)=0\}\neq\{(0,0)\}$ if $k$ is algebraically closed, so I have to prove the other direction.

My idea is to find some polynomial $f\in k[X,Y]$ such that $V(f)=\{(0,0)\}$ by using non-constant polynomial $g\in k[t]$ which has no root in $k$. But I can't find it.

How to prove?

Comment: Why the interest in the origin $(0,0)$ here? It is not a zero of for example $X+Y+1$? Is an assumption about $f$ being homogeneous missing from the question?

Comment: $V(f)\neq \{(0,0)\}$ doesn't mean $f(0,0)\neq 0$. Let $k=\mathbb{C}, f(X,Y)=X+Y+1.$ This is not a counterexample because $V(f)=\{(t,-t-1)\in\mathbb{C}^2|t\in \mathbb{C}\}\neq \{(0,0)\}$ (though $f(0,0)\neq 0$).

Comment: I know that. My point is that it is very strange to single out the point $(0,0)$. You can equally well say that $k$ is algebraically closed if and only if $V(f)\neq\{(1,13)\}$ for all $f\in k[X,Y]\setminus k$.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. That is certainly true. I found this problem in a graduate school entrance examination, so I think they fixed $(0,0)$ to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $p\in k[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $\ge 2$. Then, $f(X,Y)=Y^{\deg p}p\left(\frac XY\right)$ is a polynomial such as the ones you are looking for, because $(a,b)\in V(f)\setminus\{(0,0)\}$ if and only if $\frac ab$ is a root of $p$. On the other hand, $f$ is a homogeneous polynomial in two variables of degree $\deg p$, therefore $(0,0)\in V(f)$.